# FireZilla Ftp server Cant Connect externally

Tags: ip, ftp, port-forwarding, dmz

I have an FTP server issue and I think that the main problem is my router. The facts: A) Main desktop Windows 10 with IIS server which has a website and a Microsoft SQL server Static Ip 192.168.1.100 with port (a specific port 7510 ) forward in router and in norton.

In the same desktop I want to run a FTP SERVER. I tried with IIS but failed.

Now I am trying with FileZilla. So I installed the server and I was able to access locally with `ftp://192.168.1.100:7510` from all my pcs and my phone in the same network. I failed with my public IP or hostname (from `https://my.noip.com/`) outside from my network.

I read several blocks and I saw that the DMZ option in my router could help. When I activated the DMZ (DMZ on 192.168.1.100) I succeed to log on externally. BUT with DMZ open I can't log on from any other PC in my network to `192.168.1.100` which has the site and the SQL server. In that case I can't work in my home with my servers but can log on externally.

So is there any way to avoid DMZ activation and have externally access.

In FileZilla when DMZ is closed i get the usual stuck in connection progress

```
(external IP)> USER user_name
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - (not logged in) (external IP)> 331 Password required for user_name
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - (not logged in) (external IP)> PASS ***********
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> 230 Logged on
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> SYST
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> PWD
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> TYPE I
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> 200 Type set to I
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> SIZE /
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> 550 File not found
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> CWD /
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> 250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory.
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> PASV
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:37 μμ - user_name(external IP)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,100,212,129)
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:58 μμ - user_name(external IP)> QUIT
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:58 μμ - user_name(external IP)> 221 Goodbye
(000031)2/2/2021 12:37:58 μμ - user_name(7external IP)> disconnected.
```

Comment: IIS right martin. From outside my network I tried to connect with ftp://myhostname:7510 or  ftp://publicIP:7510. With DMZ closed these tries fails but locally can connect. With opened DMZ i can externally but no locally.

Comment: Thnx for your help. First I cant forward port 21 because my router don't allow this. it says that "it is reserved for internal usage. Please use a different port." So  I use 7510. The 192.168.1.00 is tha static ip of my desktop. So I didnt understant yor first suggestion about configure the FTP server to report its external IP address...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnx Martin.
**The problem was the range of the ports.**
I forward a specific range on my router and in the firezilla passive settings. the ip settigs on default also.
So I succeded to connect externally without DMZ open.
Thanks a lot.